# Script to get structs with specific keys from a JSON like format stored in a Config File

Tags: bash

I have the following struct (JSON-like format) saved in a config file.

```
exampleStruct = {
    valueOne = {
        irrelevant_key_1 = true;
        irrelevant_key_2 = true;
        relevant_key = true;
    };
    valueTwo = {
        irrelevant_key_1 = true;
        irrelevant_key_2 = true;
        relevant_key = true;
    };
    valueThree = {
        irrelevant_key_1 = true;
        irrelevant_key_2 = true;
    };
    valueFour = {
        irrelevant_key_1 = true;
        relevant_key = true;
    };
}
```

The structs inside the main struct i.e. **valueOne**, **valueTwo** may or may not have "**relevant_key**" as a key.
I want to find the structs which have "relevant_key" as a key.
So, for the above example, I want the following list to be stored in a file

```
valueOne
valueTwo
valueFour
```

Since **valueThree** does not have "relevant_key" as a key.

I am completely new to writing scripts, is using jq an option?
I don't want the whole script as the answer, but a direction to go forward will help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: If this is a one-shot operation that is supervised by an human, you could simply grep lines that start with a tabulation (or are those multiple spaces?) and contain an equal sign. If it's for anymore than that, you will need a parser for that language, whether it is used directly to extract the desired values or to translate the data to JSON so it can be fed to `jq`.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be done once only. There are about 3000 values which may or may not have the relevant key. Can you please tell me a sample grep command for the above example?

Comment: I had misread your requirements, I wouldn't know how to solve that with `grep`; the following GNU `sed` command [works](https://ideone.com/tvUBqU) though : `search_for="relevantKey"; sed -En "/^\s+\w+\s*=\s*\{/{s/\s+(\w+).*/\1/;h;:l n;/\b$search_for\b/{x;p};/^\s+\};/b;b l}" <inputFile >outputFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert this to a valid JSON. This trickery should do it :

```
semiJson=$( printf "{\n%s\n}" "$( sed -E $'s/=/:/g;s/;/,/g;s/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/"\\1"/g;s/"true"/True/g' semiJson.sjson )")

okJson=$( python3 -c "
import json
dict = $semiJson
print(json.dumps(dict, indent='  '))
")
```

Once you have a valid JSON ( *okJson* variable in this case ) you can easily use JQ to accomplish what you intend :

```
echo "$okJson" | jq '.exampleStruct | with_entries(select(.value.relevant_key == true)) | keys'
[
  "valueFour",
  "valueOne",
  "valueTwo"
]
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: What an amazing answer! How about putting `-r` option to `jq` and adding `.[]` filter at the end so the result looks similar to the OP's desired output?